# HIdDevice.fromIdAsync always returns null

Tags: javascript, uwp, windows-10-universal, barcode-scanner, hid

I spent way too much time trying to understand the problem here. I am working with a HID Barcode Scanner, and am able to get the device information. But I am unable to get a hold of the HidDevice object even with the right device id. It always return null. Here is what I have:

```
   var selector = Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.HidDevice.getDeviceSelector(parseInt('0x1', 16), parseInt('0x6', 16));

        Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.findAllAsync(selector, null).then(
               function (deviceInfoCollection) {
                   if (deviceInfoCollection.length > 0) {
                       for (var i = 0; i < deviceInfoCollection.length; i++) {
                           var id = deviceInfoCollection.getAt(i).id;
                           return Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.HidDevice.fromIdAsync(id, Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
                       }
                   }
                   else {
                       throw "No Devices Discovered.";
                   }
               })
        .done(function (device) {
            if (device != null)
                successCallback(device.name);
        });
```

I added these device capabilities in my manifest file:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
    <Device Id="any">
      <Function Type="usage:0001 *"/>
    </Device>
  </DeviceCapability>
```

Comment: Have you tested the [CustomHidDeviceAccess](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/CustomHidDeviceAccess) sample? If not, please refer it.

Comment: Thank you. I have, and since the selectors in it were configured to work with a SuperMUTT device, I changed the usageID and usagePageID to let it pick Keyboard-like HID devices. While I see the devices listed, I was unable to connect to them. Also, I am working with JavaScript, if that makes any difference to the process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going through the same issue now. The only thing I see in your code that strikes me as odd is the following manifest tag:

```
<Device Id="any">
```

Usually, the "any" value works. But I've had issues arise where the vendor and product id are required; I'm not quite sure why, but I think it's based off the type of device/usageid. I would try hardcoding the vendor and product id's to see if it makes a difference.

Another thought: I'm guessing by the usage tag that your scanner is configured as a keyboard. You can check to see if your scanner can be configured as a non-keyboard HID device, which helped me personally. I see other people on the internet having issues where an HidDevice is returned as null because another program is using that device; in your case, the OS might already be using the keyboard and locking it out somehow.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your notes, Dave. I did try giving the vid/pid for device capability, but no luck there. And the application needs to support various kinds of Barcode scanners and  PinPads, all of which will hopefully emulate keyboards. But I experimented with the barcode scanner by putting it in the POS mode, and the Microsoft POS libraries were able to pick it up. Any way, I am trying to get the Hid mode to work to make the device setup easy. Our use case could have more than one peripheral connected at a time.